# PHP array in table using implode()

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm trying to output these arrays in a 3x4 table. At the moment it only outputs the first value of every array in a new row in a 1 column array. While it should be 3 columns with 'qualitypoint','quality' and 'q' next to eachother. And then in a new row 'technologies' , 'tech' and 't' next to eachother etc.

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIhAy.png)

```
<?php 
$Array1 = array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India','Hey');
$Array2 = array('quality', 'tech', 'Ind','He');
$Array3 = array('q', 't', 'I','H');
echo '<table border = "3px">';
echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</tr><tr>', $Array1).'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</tr><tr>', $Array2).'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</tr><tr>', $Array3).'</td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: can you show what is your expected outcome you want? its really confusing what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all that implode mess that will break on the first possible chance. First restructure your arrays and merge them into 1 array.

```
$Array[1] = array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India','Hey');
$Array[2] = array('quality', 'tech', 'Ind','He');
$Array[3] = array('q', 't', 'I','H');
```

Then simply do

```
echo '<table>';
echo '<table>';
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($j=1;$j<=3;$j++)
    {    
     echo "<td>{$Array[$j][$i]}<td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";    
}
echo '</table>';
```

**Output**

```
table>
<tr>
    <td>qualitypoint<td>
    <td>quality<td>
    <td>q<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>technologies<td>
    <td>tech<td>
    <td>t<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>India<td>
    <td>Ind<td>
    <td>I<td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Hey<td>
    <td>He<td>
    <td>H<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Tip** You can use `count()` and not worry about hardcoding the loop's limit. That way you can scale data as much as you want without changing the code

Comment: This worked but was again a 4x3 table not 3x4. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Alright thank you very much! Will be using this since it's cleaner and easier to change than Werner's answer. Thank you Hanky Panky!

Answer (score 5):

`implode('</td><td>', $Array1)`

`implode('</td><td>', $Array2)`

`implode('</td><td>', $Array3)`

Guess this is what you wanted to do...
To use `td` instead of `tr`

Comment: I need a 3x4 table not 4x3, 'qualitypoint','quality' and 'q' should be next to eachother in their own column. Thank you anyways though.

Comment: `echo '<tr><td>' . $Array1[0] . '</td><td>' . $Array2[0] . '</td><td>' . $Array3[0] . '</td></tr>';`


`echo '<tr><td>' . $Array1[1] . '</td><td>' . $Array2[1] . '</td><td>' . $Array3[1] . '</td></tr>';`


`echo '<tr><td>' . $Array1[2] . '</td><td>' . $Array2[2] . '</td><td>' . $Array3[2] . '</td></tr>';`


So this is what you need?
You can write that with loops ofc...

Comment: Hanky got what I needed, thank you very much for your help anyways!

Answer (score 2):

If you want you can also leave the arrays as they are. But the implode cannot be used that way. This will also work for you:

```
$Array1 = array('qualitypoint', 'technologies', 'India','Hey');
$Array2 = array('quality', 'tech', 'Ind','He');
$Array3 = array('q', 't', 'I','H');

echo '<table border = "3px">';
foreach($Array1 as $key => $value){
echo '<tr><td>' . $Array1[$key] .'</td><td>' . $Array2[$key] .'</td><td>' . $Array3[$key] .'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: This worked how i wanted it, thank you very much for the help!